# Date and time in android

Tags: android, datetimepicker

In my appliaction I have to store current date into the database. How can i get the current date and is there is any specific format to store date in database.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6679909/1321873

Comment: [Picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to store the date/time in long in Database and then fetch the long date/time from Database and specify the required format using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date class to get the epoch time, which could then be stored in the database as an integer. Alternatively you could convert the epoch time to regular time and store it as a date data type.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"+ "",Locale.US);
String newtime = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, [the built-in Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

1. TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
2. REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in
   Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
   Gregorian calendar.
3. INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01
   00:00:00 UTC.

Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Now for how to insert date in after it.

Use [PreparedStatement#setString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) or [#setLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong%28int,%20long%29) respectively.

Hope this explanation works for you..

Answer (score 0):

- first convert the date to be stored to  a `String` object using `SimpleDateFormat` class

code sample:

```
Date dateToBeStored = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // this format will help you to convert date to 2012/07/04 format string
String dateString = formatter.format(dateToBeStored); // convert string
```

- now read the date string from DB. you should have some means to get the date back from DB.

  ```
  String readDateStringFromDB = readDate();
  ```
- Now parse the read date string to date object by `parse` method of `SimpleDateFormat` class

  ```
  Date dateObj = formatter.parse(readDateStringFromDB);  // now you have the Date object back
  ```